# Getting text from low-quality gif file with tesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

```
import pytesseract


import requests
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image,ImageOps

image_url = 'gif'

def optimize_and_ocr_from_url(image_url, tesseract_config="--psm 6"):
    # Download the image from the URL
    response = requests.get(image_url)
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

    # Optimize the image (resize, convert to grayscale, etc.)
    optimized_image = optimize_image(image)

    # Use Tesseract OCR to extract text from the optimized image
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(optimized_image, config=tesseract_config)

    # Print the OCR result to the console
    print("OCR Result:")
    print(text)

def optimize_image(image, target_resolution=(109, 50)):
    # Resize the image to the target resolution
    resized_image = image.resize(target_resolution)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    grayscale_image = ImageOps.grayscale(resized_image)

    return grayscale_image

# Example usage
optimize_and_ocr_from_url(image_url)
```

I am trying to convert this type of images to text
[This is the type of image i am trying to convert to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy5eo.gif)

I tried to grayscale,tried to play with the tesseract_config but it doesn't seem to work.There is just empty response.I tried other solutions on stackoverflow but couldnt managed to do it.
I use windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use your `gif` directly with `tesseract` (instead of `pytesseract`) in `console`/`terminal`/`bash` (on Linux)

```
$ tesseract input.gif stdout

Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 270
Empty page!!
Estimating resolution as 270
Empty page!!
```

Next I tried to `convert` it with `imagemagick` and it seems it has few problems:

- it needs to add information about `dpi` to file but it seems `gif` can't keep it so I had to convert to `png`.
- it is too small so I resized it to `200x24`
- it is transparent (it doesn't have background) so (to make sure) I addad white background (but it seems `tesseract` doesn't need it, but it is more readable when I check it in any image viewer)

```
$ convert input.gif -resize 200x24 -units pixelsperinch -density 72 -background white -flatten output.png
```

`output.png`

[image]

Now it recognizes text but there is another problem:
There is no `top margin` so it has problem to recognize `7` - it detects `/`

```
+3/0 3/7 312208
```

So I used `-gravity south -extent 200x28` to add margin

```
$ convert input.gif -resize 200x24 -units pixelsperinch -density 72 -background white -flatten -gravity south -extent 200x28 output-with-margin.png
```

and now `tesseract` detects number correctly.

`output-with-margin.png` (`Stackoverflow` has white background so you can't see new margin)

[image]

---

You can try to do the same with `Pillow` or you may use `subprocess.run()` to run directly [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/) or you may try to use Python module [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/) which uses `imagemagick`

---

**EDIT:**

It doesn't need top margin if I use `digits`, `+` and `space`

```
$ tesseract output.png stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist='+0123456789 '
```

---

**EDIT:**

I checked all options in `tesseract` and it has `--dpi` - and it can use `gif` with option `--dpi 72` but not with `--dpi 70` (maybe if you resize even more then `70` will work).
But image still has to be resized to `200x24`, and may need white background to recognize `7`.
I didn't test combination: with top margin and without background.

```
$ tesseract output.gif stdout --dpi 72 -c tessedit_char_whitelist='+0123456789 '
```

---

**EDIT:**

In `Tesseract` documentation you can see [Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)